# How can i update the value of my session?

Tags: php, laravel

Why is my session variable is becoming EMPTY after I replace it with a new value?

```
  public function process(){

    $category_id = Session::get('category_id'); // [1,2,3] 
    $category_type = Session::get('category_type'); //[1,2]

    array_shift($category_id);
    array_shift($category_type);

    $category_id_new = $category_id;
    $category_type_new = $category_type;

    session()->put('category_id', $category_id_new);
    session()->put('category_type', $category_type_new);

    print_r($category_id_new);
    print_r($category_type_new);

  }
```

here is my another code and still doesn't work

```
  public function progress(){

    $category_id = Session::get('category_id'); // [1,2,3] then splice to go to another category.
    $category_type = Session::get('category_type'); //[1,2]

    array_shift($category_id);
    array_shift($category_type);


    Session::put('category_id', $category_id);
    Session::put('category_type', $category_type);

    print_r(Session::get('category_id'));
    print_r(Session::get('category_type'));
}
```

My process is to get the SESSION then use array_shift just to removed the first index, then save it again to my session, but when I saved it, it is becoming empty. is there a way to fix this? please help me.

I really don't know what to do :(. Can someone help me on how can I move forward with the problem that I have, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: remove and re create

Comment: I already tried it sir, i already remove the session which is the category_id and category_type using the ```session()->forget('category_id');``` and tried to recreate again, but it is empty. :(

Comment: I am already out of options on how to fix this :(

Comment: What laravel version are you on?

Comment: I am using laravel 7 sir.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one using unset

```
           session()->put('category_id',[1,2,3]); // [1,2,3]
           session()->put('category_type',[1,2]); //[1,2]

            $categories = session()->get('category_id');
            $category_types = session()->get('category_type');

             unset($categories[0]);
            unset($category_types[0]);

             session()->put('category_id',$categories);
             session()->put('category_type',$category_types);
//             return true;
            dd(session()->get('category_id'),session()->get('category_type'));
```

Comment: if you unsupported this question, please explain why